# AsymptoticSolve for the Inverse

Tags: equation-solving, asymptotics

How can I find an asymptotic expansion for the inverse of the function $f[x]=x(1+x^{1/4})$ near $0$?

---

I tried substituting $z=x^{1/4}$ and using `AsymptoticSolve` to solve $y = z^4+z^5$ for $z[y]$ and then do $x[y] = z[y]^4$.

```
(z /. AsymptoticSolve[y == z^(4) + z^(5), {z, 0}, {y, 0, 1}][[1]])^(4)
(* output x[y] = (-y^(1/4) - Sqrt[y]/4 - (7 y^(3/4))/32 - y/4)^4 *)
```

If this is indeed the inverse, the difference $x[f[x]]-x$ should be small. When I do a series expansion for this difference, the leading term is $2 x^{5/4}$, but I suspect I am not doing things correctly since if I just try $x[y] = y(1-y^{1/4})$ as the inverse of $f$, I get a better leading term for $x[f[x]]-x$. I get something of the order $x^{3/2}$.

Comment: Have you already seen `InverseSeries[]`?

Comment: Thanks! Something like: `InverseSeries[x + x^(4/3) + O[x]^2] `?

Comment: Any help?: `z /. AsymptoticSolve[y == z^(4) + z^(5), {z, 0}, {y, 0, 1}][[1]] /. 
  First@Solve[y == z^(4) + z^(5), y] // 
 Series[#, {z, 0, 3}, Assumptions -> z > 0] &` -- Note which branch was chosen, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2, what do you get for the inverse of `f`?

Comment: The same as you I guess, but the branch is for the solution to `y == x - x^(5/4)`.  Since the 4th root has four branches, you have to pay attention to which was chosen by `AsymptoticSolve`. What you want is `asol = AsymptoticSolve[y == z^(4) + z^(5), {z, 0}, {y, 0, 2}][[4]]`, the last branch returned instead of the first.

Comment: @Michael E2: in the result presented by me, `Assumptions -> x </> 0` changes nothing.

Comment: @user64494 Me neither.  Assumptions are not used as constraints, it seems.

Comment: @Micael E2: The plot `Plot[x + x^(5/4), {x, 0, 2}]` suggests there is  only one real-valued inverse function of  `x - x^(5/4)` near zero.

Comment: @user64494 You have to work over the complex numbers.  `Plot` does not do that.

Comment: @Michael E2:Thank you for your intuitive opinion.  `InverseFunction[# (1 + #^(1/4)) &][x]` produces `Root[-x^4 + 4 x^3 #1 - 6 x^2 #1^2 + 4 x #1^3 - #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]`. If I was not mistaken, the four other roots (two of them are complex-valued near the origin) are not confirmed by substitution.`x->0.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is somewhat unclearly formulated. If I correctly understand it, the following does the job.

```
Series[InverseFunction[# (1 + #^(1/4)) &][x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

> $x-x^{5/4}+\frac{5 x^{3/2}}{4}-\frac{55 x^{7/4}}{32}+\frac{5 x^2}{2}+O\left(x^{9/4}\right)$

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. (what was unclear? perhaps I can edit the question)

Comment: @Cantor: You denote by $x$ both  argument of $f(x)$ and  argument of $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work if I change 1/4 to 1/3.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in one of my comments, $y = z^4 + z^5$ has four branches in the neighborhood of $z=0$.  `AsymptoticSolve` returns asymptotic series for all four.  The last one is the one corresponding to $y = x+x^{5/4}$:

```
ClearAll[asol];
asol[n_] :=  (* n = order of series sought *)
  AsymptoticSolve[y == z^(4) + z^(5), {z, 0}, {y, 0, n}][[4]];

z^4 /. asol[2];
Series[%, {y, 0, 2}]
(*
y - y^(5/4) + (5 y^(3/2))/4 - (55 y^(7/4))/32 + (5 y^2)/2 -
 (7735 y^(9/4))/2048 + (3003 y^(5/2))/512 -
 (609615 y^(11/4))/65536 + O[y]^3
*)
```

The error that the OP was interested in ($x(f(x)) - x$):

```
z^4 /. asol[1] /. y -> (x + x^(5/4));
Series[% - x, {x, 0, 2}]
(*
-((663 x^2)/512) + (381 x^(9/4))/2048 - (1113 x^(5/2))/8192 +
 (3485 x^(11/4))/32768 + O[x]^3
*)

z^4 /. asol[2] /. y -> (x + x^(5/4));
Series[% - x, {x, 0, 3}]
(*
-((13042315 x^3)/2097152) - (34610147 x^(13/4))/8388608 +
 (46787 x^(7/2))/4194304 + (284843 x^(15/4))/16777216 + O[x]^4
*)
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, the inverse function of $y=z^4+z^5 $ has five branches in the neighborhood of $y=0$.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: the result of`Table[Root[-y + #1^4 + #1^5 &, k] /. y -> 0, {k, 1, 5}]` is `{-1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: @user64494 OK, but how does that relate to what I said?